# Android - get duration of AMR audio file programmatically

Tags: android, audio, wav, amr

How do I get duration of an AMR file?

```
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

I want to get the duration of the file after the recording is stopped WITHOUT creating any MediaPlayer and get the duration from it. For a regular Wav file I simply do this:

```
fileLength / byteRate
```

but for AMR I didn't know the byteRate and I'm not sure this will be ok though since WAV is raw PCM data(uncompressed) and AMR is compressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the 3GP container contains information about the content length? The [3GPP file format spec](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.244/) is available if you want to read it.

---

For a raw .amr file you'd have to traverse all the frames to find the length of the audio, since each frame can be encoded with a different bitrate.

The process for doing this would be:

- Skip the first 6 bytes of the file (the AMR signature).
- The rest of the file will be audio frames, which each starts with a one-byte header. Read that byte and look at bits 3..6 (the codec mode). For AMR-NB the valid codec modes are 0..7, which you can map to the size of the frame in bytes using the table below.
- Once you know the size of the current frame, skip past it and parse the next frame. Repeat until you reach the end of the file.

If you've counted the number of frames in the file you can multiply that number by 20 to get the length of the audio in milliseconds.

**Frame size table:**

```
Codec mode  Frame size
----------------------
0             13
1             14
2             16
3             18
4             20
5             21
6             27
7             32
```

([Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140422184907/http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/AMR_format))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot. I guess I can even append 2 amr files by simply getting all bytes starting with th 7-th one from a file and attaching them to the end of the second one. Just appending frames... I wander if I must modify something in the appended file header, but I guess not...

Comment: The file header should just be a signature identifying the contents as AMR-NB data, so concatenation should work the way you described it. I haven't tested it myself, though.

Comment: @AlexandruCircus : using bits 3,4,5,6 I am getting 9 (1-0-0-1) , the table only maps till 7, did you encounter such cases? If yes, what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: @SRB: That's probably a SID frame (Silence Insertion Descriptor - used for producing comfort noise).

Comment: Hi @Michael, so what is the frame size for such frame? Do we still use the bits 3 to 5 and derive the frame size based on the table in the above answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what the size is for SID frames. You might be able to find documentation for that online if you search around.

Comment: Hey Michael, I'm facing a similar challenge, but my files are AMR-WB, specifically `.awb`. I'm curious, would the algorithm you described still work? If not, do you know any resources where I could understand the format? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Java Code:
https://blog.csdn.net/fjh658/article/details/12869073

C# Code (From MemoryStream):

```
private double getAmrDuration(MemoryStream originalAudio)
    {
            double duration = -1;
            int[] packedSize = new int[] { 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 26, 31, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            long length = originalAudio.Length;
            int pos = 6;

            int frameCount = 0;

            int packedPos = -1;

            byte[] datas = new byte[1];

            while ((pos <= length))
            {
            originalAudio.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                if ((originalAudio.Read(datas, 0, 1) != 1))
                {
                    duration = length > 0 ? ((length - 6) / 650) : 0;
                    break;
                }


                packedPos = (datas[0] >> 3) & 0x0F;
                pos += packedSize[packedPos] + 1;
                frameCount++;
            }

            /// //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            duration = (duration + (frameCount * 20));
            // 'p*20

        return duration/1000;
    }
```

Comment: Minor feedback: It would help if you added context along with this answer rather than straight copy/pasting code. Thanks for the answer!